# Symfony2 relationship bug OneToOne unidirectional

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine, symfony-2.7

Here is a small problem that bothers me for a while and as I still do not master completely the relationship between entity I can not solve it despite my pile of research ....

I have an entity " Activite " in which I have a OneToOne relation to an entity " ActiviteImage " knowing that an activity does not necessarily associate a picture :

```html
class Activite
{
    ....
 
    /**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="ISC\PlatformBundle\Entity\ActiviteImage", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
     */
    private $image;
 
    ....
 
    /**
     * Set image
     *
     * @param \ISC\PlatformBundle\Entity\ActiviteImage $image
     * @return Activite
     */
    public function setImage(ActiviteImage $image = null)
    {
        $this->image = $image;
 
        return $this;
    }
 
    /**
     * Get image
     *
     * @return \ISC\PlatformBundle\Entity\ActiviteImage
     */
    public function getImage()
    {
        return $this->image;
    }
}
```

```html
class ActiviteImage
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;
 
    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="urlImage", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $urlImage;
}
```

my controller when the form is submitted :

```html
$activite->setTextActivity($contentActu);
$activite->setIdFriend(0);
$activite->setDatetimeActivity(new \DateTime());
$image = new ActiviteImage();
$image->setUrlImage('http://127.0.0.1:81/IMC/web/uploads/img/'.$fileName);
$activite->setImage($image);
$em->persist($activite);
$em->flush();
```

Do not rely on the plain address, these are only tests for now .

The addition of the two entities database works only when I will look to manually check the operation in my Activity Table image_id column is empty, it is not NULL, just empty (so no connection with ActiviteImage the table ) ....

( And if it helps you , I know we should not touch directly to the table but I try to tell the id of the image, phpMyAdmin does not return an error , just "0 posted online " cf. image -> http://imageshack.com/a/img923/3784/tSiY9d.png)

Other information that can be useful when I go watch the application executed by Symfony I perceive myself that this is good :

```html
INSERT INTO activite (idUser, idTypeActivite, idFriend, textActivity, datetimeActivity, image_id) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
 
Parameters: { 1: 1, 2: 2, 3: 0, 4: fghgfh, 5: '2016-09-07 16:30:13', 6: 1 }
```

I returned several times to the tutorial of Winzou on Openclassroom thinking I missed something but if that's the case I do not see what ...

So if you had a small track to give me for this problem persists and is relatively troublesome : uh :

( Not easy to understand the relationship ... :( )

Thanks in advance,

Kay

Answer (score 0):

Where is your OneToOne relation from ActiviteImage -> Activite?

I would set the relationship up as bidirectional, e.g. you should have mappedBy and inversedBy in your relations.

See the [documentation](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html#one-to-one-bidirectional).

E.g.

```
class Activite
{
    // ...

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="ActiviteImage", mappedBy="activite", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
     */
    private $activiteImage;

    // ...
}

/** @Entity */
class ActiviteImage
{
    // ...

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Activite", inversedBy="activiteImage")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="activite_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $activite;

    // ...
}
```

It should work correctly when you have set up your relations correctly.